# Mindmap color shading between root node and children not using correct color

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps, tikzlibrary

I am trying to create a mindmap in `tikz`, bur running in problems when I define the color of the root node different from the "default one". Mainly, the shading between the connection of the root node and hist children is not using the correct color, as you can see in the following image. How can I solve this?

[image]

and this is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[border = 3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\pagestyle{empty} % Clear page

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[% Tikz picture options and styles on midmap
        mindmap, 
        every node/.style={concept, execute at begin node=\hskip0pt},
        root concept/.append style={
            concept color=gray,text width = 3cm},
        concept color = yellow, % Default node color
        text = white,                   % Default text color
        grow cyclic,
        level 1/.append style={level distance=6cm,sibling angle=60},
        level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=90},
        level 3/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=90},
        ]
        
        \node[root concept]{Hello!}
        child[concept color=red]  { node {This is a red node}
        }
        child [concept color=blue]{ node{This is a blue node}
            child[concept color=orange]{node{This is a orange node}}
            child[concept color=green]{node{This is a green node}}
        };
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Maybe is relevant to this issue, but I have found that there are colors from the `xcolor` package that also have this strange behavior. For instance, consider the following image, by using the cyan color:

[image]

Ans the corresponsing code:

```
\documentclass[border = 3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\pagestyle{empty} % Clear page

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[% Tikz picture options and styles on midmap
        mindmap, 
        every node/.style={concept, execute at begin node=\hskip0pt},
        root concept/.append style={
            concept color=gray,text width = 3cm},
        concept color = yellow, % Default node color
        text = white,                   % Default text color
        grow cyclic,
        level 1/.append style={level distance=6cm,sibling angle=60},
        level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=90},
        level 3/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=90},
        ]
        \clip (0,-1) rectangle ++(8,7);
        \node[root concept]{Hello!}
        child[concept color=red]  { node {This is a red node}
        }
        child [concept color=cyan]{ node{This is a cyan node}
            child[concept color=orange]{node{This is a orange node}}
            child[concept color=green]{node{This is a green node}}
        };
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For this MWE you can solve it easily by setting the default node color to gray, but I guess you also want actual yellow default nodes?

Comment: @Marijn its more that I would like to know why is not working as it should. As I understand from the tikz manual, by changing the color of concept, the color of the nexus between nodes should also change

Comment: It could be a bug, i.e., maybe the gradient looks only at the default `concept color` setting and the settings given directly as arguments to child nodes, but when a color definition is set inside of a `.append style` definition then possibly the gradient does not 'see' it. I'm not sure that this is indeed the case though, I didn't check the source code.

Comment: @Marijn you are completely right. The result is fine when I take awy the color declaration on the root node. Now the only problem that remains is the weird coloring using xcolor, but I will use normal color declarations instead of that package and thats it. Thanks!

Comment: If you load `xcolor` with option `cmyk` or `rgb` the colors match. It seems that the default color model behaviour doesn't place nices with shadings. Explicitly using one of the two main ones apparently keeps `xcolor` more consistent.

Comment: The first `concept color` gets applied to the (root) node where as the others get applied on the `child` label. Doing `\path[root concept] node{}` instead works.